# Using IPMITOOL to disable a fan sensor

Tags: fan, sensors, ipmi

I am no longer using FAN3 in my system. But there is still a lower/upper sensor bound set for it. I had set that previously using [ipmitool](https://github.com/ipmitool/ipmitool).

How can I use ipmitool to set all the values back to ***na*** instead of 0?

Because currently, the lower threshold causes assertions, and all fans to run at full blast.

```
FAN1             | 1300.000   | RPM        | ok    | 100.000   | 200.000   | 300.000   | 3000.000  | 4000.000  | 5000.000  
FAN2             | na         |            | na    | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        
FAN3             | 0.000      | RPM        | nr    | 0.000     | 0.000     | 0.000     | 3000.000  | 4000.000  | 5000.000  
FAN4             | na         |            | na    | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        
FANA             | na         |            | na    | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        
FANB             | 1300.000   | RPM        | ok    | 100.000   | 200.000   | 300.000   | 3000.000  | 4000.000  | 5000.000
```

I want FAN3 to read ***na*** like FAN2, FAN4 and FANA do.

Things that I have tried:

- $ sudo ipmitool sensor thresh FAN3 lower 0 0 0 *(does not stop the assertion)*
- $ sudo ipmitool sensor thresh FAN3 lower -1 -1 -1 *(not accepted)*
- $ sudo ipmitool sensor thresh FAN3 lower na na na *(not accepted)*

This is on a Microdata X11-SRM-F running Ubuntu.

The assertion that causes full blast fans:

```
$ sudo ipmitool sel list
   1 | 09/30/2020 | 23:39:46 | Unknown #0xff |  | Asserted
   2 | 10/08/2020 | 17:38:54 | Fan #0x43 | Lower Critical going low  | Asserted
   3 | 10/08/2020 | 17:38:54 | Fan #0x43 | Lower Non-recoverable going low  | Asserted
   4 | 10/08/2020 | 17:43:50 | Fan #0x43 | Lower Critical going low  | Asserted
   5 | 10/08/2020 | 17:43:50 | Fan #0x43 | Lower Non-recoverable going low  | Asserted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reboot would keep the fan assertion enabled.

However: physically switching the computer off at the power supply did the trick: FAN3 is now listed as ***na***.

So you need to actually cut the power before the ghost fan goes away.

Alternatively, if `ipmitool` works for your system you can utilize a cold mc reset to clear out that status without removing power from your system. You will have to wait about 70-90 seconds after running this command to work with your IPMI again. Run the command as follows:

```
$ ipmitool mc reset cold
```

Comment: Makes sense. Even though fan speeds set via IPMI (on boards that support this) are not stateful between reboots, the thresholds are. Unless - as you said - you take care to force the BMC to re-initialize the fan headers on boot. I'll add that although your technique worked in your case, it very much depends on the BMC chip in play, the BIOS and middleware. So, YMMV. In general, I'd suggest a full cold start, meaning unplug the server, wait at least 1 minute for residual power to fade from all systems, then plug-in and boot. MOST boards will perform a fan inventory from a true cold start.